# R shiny: input can be selected through conditional panel

Tags: r, input, shiny, conditional-statements

I want to have a full conditional panel over the app that I am building to function as a disclaimer. The conditional panel needs to cover the full screen until the user accepts the disclaimer. After that, the conditional panel clears and the user can use the app.

Currently, multiple inputs appear to be clickable though the conditional panel (radio buttons as well as a filter). When I select things in the filter, the app runs in the background). I don't want this to be possible. How can i get the conditional panel to cover the whole screen including all inputs?

```
    conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.disclaimerweg == ""',
                 absolutePanel(id = "disclaimer", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE,
                               draggable = FALSE, top = 41, left = 0, right = 0, bottom =  0,
                               width = "auto", height = "auto",
                               br(),
                               #actionButton("demoversie", "Demoversie"),
                               br(),
                               h1("Disclaimer!"),
                               actionButton("disclaimerweg", "Akkoord"),
                               br(),
                               br()

                 )
)
```

[image: "Input can be selected through conditional panel]

Comment: I don't know if you really need to rely on a conditional panel here. I'd use a sweet alert from the `shinyWidgets` package, which must be accepted by the user. See: https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks, that looks like something I could use as well. How can I get the alert to open upon launching the app, without a user needing to click an action button?

Comment: You'll need the function `sendSweetAlert()` (see: https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyWidgets/man/sendSweetAlert.html) and probably connect it to an `observeEvent({})` that observes the launch of your app. I suppose a quick websearch will get you there. E.g. `sendSweetAlert(session, title = "Attention", text = HTML("Your Text"), type = "success",
                       btn_labels = "I accept", html = TRUE, closeOnClickOutside = FALSE)`.

Comment: I will have a look, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i'm understanding your question, but you can put your buttons inside other conditional Panel that meet the oposite condition:

```
conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.disclaimerweg == ""',
             absolutePanel(id = "disclaimer", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE,
                           draggable = FALSE, top = 41, left = 0, right = 0, bottom =  0,
                           width = "auto", height = "auto",
                           br(),
                           #actionButton("demoversie", "Demoversie"),
                           br(),
                           h1("Disclaimer!"),
                           actionButton("disclaimerweg", "Akkoord"),
                           br(),
                           br()

             )
)

  conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.disclaimerweg != ""',
  # Input: Select a file ----
  fileInput("fileUploaded", "Choose CSV File",
            multiple = FALSE,
            accept = c("text/csv",
                       "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                       ".csv"))
)
```

Then the buttons only appear when the user click the banner. Hope it helps!